# Meaning of 次の日はないようにする

Tags: grammar, translation, words

The sentence is found in a monologue about a persons working habits, particularly how they don't have time to sleep, and are constantly working at their 3 jobs.

The paragraph goes:

> ほとんど寝てなかったね。朝帰ってきて、ちょっとベッド入って、また家庭教師行って。で、スーパー、その次の日はないようにしてたりです。

The part I don't understand is the

> 次の日はないようにしてたりです。

I understand ようにする is to do habitually, but the 日は is throwing me off. Could it mean "working in a way so there there is no next day"?

Answer (score 1):

> 「ほとんど[寝]{ね}てなかったね。[朝帰]{あさかえ}ってきて、ちょっとベッド[入]{はい}って、また[家庭教師]{かていきょうし}[行]{い}って。で、スーパー、その[次]{つぎ}の[日]{ひ}はないようにしてたりです。」

This is written so informally that it almost sounds like it was casually spoken.  The 「～～してたりです」 ending is sort of "new" and definitely "in".

「次の日はないようにしてたりです」

≒「次の日は[仕事]{しごと}がないようにしていたりします」

≒ "then, I would (occasionally) try not to do any work the next day"

"Next day" refers to the day after this person had to work all day long.  This phrase suggests that s/he has a good amount of control as to which days (of the week) s/he has to go to any of his/her three jobs.

> I understand ようにする is to do habitually

Not in this case.  Here it means "to do something so that ~~"